# Determine the number of graphs.

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, inclusion-exclusion

For vertex set $\{1, 2, \dots, n\}$, how can I find the number of graphs having no component with exactly two vertices?

I thought about the number of graphs in an ignition method, and I was worried that something was complicated and weird....

Comment: Please include more details if you intend to get a good answer. What is your working definition of a graph? Are self-loops allowed? Multiple edges connecting a pair of vertices? Are edges oriented (usually called a *digraph*)? Most importantly, **what have you tried and where did you get stuck?**

Comment: This is probably better handled by counting the excluded class - find the number of graphs which have one or more components of two linked vertices. Presumably you know the number of possible (simple) graphs on $n$ vertices, so also the number on $n{-}2$ vertices is clear; then count ways to pick two to exist in a component alone, then roll through the inclusion-exclusion process.

Answer (score 2):

Here we have using the combinatorial class $\mathcal{G}$ of all labeled
graphs and $\mathcal{C}$ the class of all connected labeled graphs the
relation

$$\def\textsc#1{\dosc#1\csod}
\def\dosc#1#2\csod{{\rm #1{\small #2}}}
\mathcal{G} = \textsc{SET}(\mathcal{C})$$

This gives for the corresponding EGFs the relation

$$G(z) = \exp C(z).$$

Now we have from first principles that

$$G(z) = \sum_{n\ge 0} 2^{n\choose 2} \frac{z^n}{n!}$$

so that

$$C(z) =
\log \sum_{n\ge 0} 2^{n\choose 2} \frac{z^n}{n!}.$$

Canceling the connected graph on two nodes we get

$$D(z) = -\frac{z^2}{2}
+ \log \sum_{n\ge 0} 2^{n\choose 2} \frac{z^n}{n!}.$$

The class of graphs with no connected components on two nodes
therefore has specification

$$\mathcal{H} = \textsc{SET}(\mathcal{D})$$

so that

$$H(z) = \exp(-z^2/2)
\sum_{n\ge 0} 2^{n\choose 2} \frac{z^n}{n!}.$$

Extracting coefficients here we get for $n! [z^n] H(z)$

$$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #00A000]{
n! \sum_{q=0}^{\lfloor n/2 \rfloor}
\frac{(-1)^q}{2^q \times q!} 
\frac{2^{n-2q\choose 2}}{(n-2q)!}.}$$

This gives the sequence

$$1, 1, 1, 5, 55, 959, 31883, 2076383, 267530657, \ldots$$

which is [OEIS A093352](https://oeis.org/A093352) where these data are
confirmed. The combinatorial classes are from *Analytic Combinatorics* by
Flajolet  and Sedgewick.